# Vectorize vertex-face membership matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am doing some experimentation with meshes on Matlab. Here is what I have:

- **3 X #Verts** matrix that contains all the vertices
- **3 X #Faces** matrix that contains all the faces in my mesh.

Here is what I am trying to create efficiently:

- A **#Verts X #Faces** binary matrix **Mem**. An entry **Mem(i, j) = 1** if vertex i is one of the vertices of triangle j.

Here is how I do it in a very inefficient way now (I don't know much about Matlab vectorization so please excuse my ignorance):

```
numVerts = size(verts, 2);
numFaces = size(faces, 2);
mem = sparse(numVerts, numFaces);

for i = 1:size(verts, 2)
    mem(i,:) = any(faces == i);
end
```

Here is some numerical data to be able to test this code:

```
verts = [0 0 1 1; 0 1 0 1; 0 0 0 0];
faces = [1 3; 2 2; 3 4];
```

Each column of the **verts** matrix is the coordinates of a vertex. For example, the 4 vertices here are located at positions (0,0,0), (0,1,0), (1,0,0), and (1,1,0).

Each column of the **faces** matrix is the indices of 3 vertices that belong to a face. For example, the faces of the mesh defined above are 2 triangles that are defined as containing the vertices (1,2,3) and (3,2,4).

This will create a simple mesh that contains 4 vertices and 2 triangles.
The **mem** matrix in this case is:

```
mem = [1 0; 1 1; 1 1; 0 1]
```

Here, for example, mem(2,1) = 1 which means that face number 1 contains vertex number 2.
Any pointers on how can I do it more efficiently?

Comment: how is a "face" defined? please post a minimal numerical example of your input data and the desired output; what do you want to do with that binary matrix? regarding your "general" request please read [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic  ...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @m.s. thanks for the comment. I added numeric data and also removed the off-topic question.

Comment: Still don't understand how a face is defined. What are these numbers in each row?

Comment: @Bentoy13 I explained the meaning of the numerical data better. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go! Lets understand why this should be faster (I haven't profiled it, but I am 99.99% sure it will be faster).

One of the things you shoudl known about sparse matrices is: It is **way** faster to first compute where to put the values, and then create the matrix in one go than it is to go filling it. This is true due to the way they are stored in memory.

Therefore lets do that. In your problem there is one nice thing: `faces` actually do contain the row index of the elements you want to fill in `mem`! And the columns are easy, they are just 3-1s, 3-2s, 3-3s,.... 3-`numFaces`! We can easily build an array like that using `repmat`. Therefore this is the code:

```
numVerts = size(verts, 2);
numFaces = size(faces, 2);

jj= repmat(1:numFaces,[3,1]);  % 3 vtx in each face
jj=jj(:)';

mem = sparse( faces(:),jj,1,numVerts,numFaces);
```

however, if you are just working with logicals, make the matrix a logical and save lots of memory!

```
mem = sparse( faces(:),jj,true,numVerts,numFaces);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's work fast. And thanks for the logicals tip too, I didn't know that either.